# Ms visual studio 2012 has stopped working (WinForms)

Tags: winforms

If i try to open Form by view designer(or if i click to open form)

I get below exeption,

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working
```

After that , it re open project but still same problem..

**I tried to delete below but problem still occurs.**

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio ...\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"=""
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: how about a system restart? or have you recently installed any VS extensions?

Comment: it  do that with all project ? ; try to create a new project and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

try to delete all temporary files created by Visual Studio. Have a look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/11/08/clean-up-after-visual-studio.aspx)